# How should I use ML to extract the entries from a dictionary?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning, named-entity-recognition, methodology, information-extraction

**A question about methodology**
I know that methodology questions are not welcome on the Stack Overflow site, but I don't know if they are acceptable here. If they are not, I apologize.

**Description of the problem**
I have a **dictionary** file in the .txt extension.
It was made using an OCR tool designed for the English language.
It is a Latin dictionary in which each entry has declension, etymology, definitions and quotes.

**What I need:**
To select every entry.
To remove the quotations.
To format the text, mainly removing some empty lines, applying italic and bold to some parts of the text.
The formatting will be made using markdown, so I would circumscribe the word that has to be in bold, for example, with asterisks.

**What I have tried:**
Although almost certain that it would not work, I tried to use Regex. But it is a much **irregular and complicated text**.

**Possible methodologies to use**
I thought of using supervised learning, by teaching the program what is an entry in the dictionary.

**Background**
I have been programming in Python for some years, but I have no experience in Machine Learning. I apologize if this question is not pertinent.
I am skimming the book Hands-on Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow, trying to find a solution.

Would ML be the proper solution?
Could I format the text showing to the program how I want the final result to be? Meaning, showing some hundreds of already formatted data?
Can the program extract those sections of text and, when fed with desired output, recognize the changes to be made in the text?
Which methods can I use?
Could you point me in a direction?

Comment: Hi @lima, welcome to the site. OCR text usually contains garbled text and it's not easy to parse. One option would be to use a LLM with an appropriate prompt to clean the text and format it.